# Use different port or context for webservices in wildfly

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wildfly-8, java-ee-7

This is my scenario:

> Wildfly 8.2.0
>
> ejb-jar with 2-webservices deployed in ear-packaging
>
> several web-war each with one-webservice deployed as standalone wars

My problem is that the webservices calls hit my servlet filters, which contains very complex logic, and does some permanent and temporary redirects.

Currently, i cannot ascertain how this will affect external services that depend on these webservices, but on my development and test environment, the redirect dont affect much, but i would like to avoid hitting my main application logic from the webservice calls.

What have i tried?

wildfly webservice subsystem:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>

    <!-- tried <wsdl-host>subdomain.mydomain.com</wsdl-host> -->
    <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
    <wsld-port>http-port</wsld-port>
    <wsld-secure-port>https-port</wsdl-secure-port>
</subsytem>
```

Even i setup the ports as in the above configurations, i am unable to access the webservices anymore. specifying the wsdl-host manually does not help either.

- Could it be possible, that within the same deployed module, i can
  specify a different port for my webservices?
- And if a specify a different port, would these go through a different
  lifecycle without hitting my main webapplication filter chains?

Comment: did you paste the XML sample or freehand type it? I ask because `<wsld-port>` is misspelled (try `wsdl-port`) and `wsld-secure-port` is as well (and does not match with the intended closing tag)

Comment: @scotth if that were the case, wildfly wont even start cause the document will be ill-formed and invalid. No, i did not misspell the words in the actual standalone-full.xml